# Text Centre after Automatic Vertical Flip

Tags: javascript, css

I am newly start PHP development. I have multiple text on screen, I want to take text centre of screen after text flip. I try google first so I got css code. As I am new so not able to make it works.

If its wrong question then let me know I can delete it.

Thanks in advance.

My code can explain you in more details.

```css
/*Vertical Flip*/
.verticalFlip{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
}
.verticalFlip span{
    animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

/*Vertical Flip Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

.bgimg{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.imgcentered {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    /*top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

.sentence{
    font-size: 75px;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimg">
    <div class="imgcentered">
        <h2 class="sentence">WE ARE<div class="verticalFlip">
                <span>INDIAN</span>
                <span>Perfection</span>
                <span>Trustworthy</span>
                <span>Responsive</span>
                <span>Supportive</span>
            </div>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Text centred in what way? It looks like it already has a `text-align: center` on it. Could you describe what the desired outcome is please? Is there any javascript in there?

Comment: @MattFletcher What I wan to do when text change I want to move it to centre. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are to do with the box model. The way you're showing those words is by fading the opacities in and out, but they still take up space. Because of this you've set their position to `absolute`. When it's absolute, it can't add any extra width to the box, and so CSS's default centring won't work. However, if you take the absolute off, there's no way of getting them to all sit on top of each other as you can't animate at `display: none` onto it.

I would recommend taking off the `position: absolute` and not relying on CSS to do the delay/timing. Instead add some simple JS with a `setInterval` that will, on each interval, add a class (for example `active`) to the next span in the list, removing the class from the others. Then set the display none on the inactive ones and `display: inline-block` on the active one.

Either way, you will need to either set the left position dynamically with javascript, or do the looping with javascript. I don't believe there's a way of doing it with just pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*Vertical Flip*/
.verticalFlip{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 8px;
}
.verticalFlip span{
    animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    -webkit-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
    color: #00abe9;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 10s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}
.verticalFlip span:nth-child(6){
    animation-delay: 12.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12.5s;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(7){
    animation-delay: 15s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 15s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
}


/*Vertical Flip Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes vertical{
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg); }
    10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

.bgimg{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.imgcentered {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    /*top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

.sentence{
    font-size: 75px;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimg">
    <div class="imgcentered">
        <h2 class="sentence">WE ARE<div class="verticalFlip">
                <span>INDIAN</span>
                <span>Perfection</span>
                <span>Trustworthy</span>
                <span>Responsive</span>
                <span>Supportive</span>
                <span>Responsive</span>
                <span>Supportive</span>
            </div>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but using multiple text(6 or more). the text was overlaped